# Power functions and $\lim_{x \to +\infty}{\frac{\int_{0}^{x}{f(t)\mathrm{d}t}}{x f(x)}}=\frac{1}{1 + \beta}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

Let $f : \mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ an increasing continuous function such that $f(0) = 0$ and $\beta \geq 0$. When we have for all $x > 0$, $\displaystyle\frac{\int_{0}^{x}{f(t)\mathrm{d}t}}{x f(x)} = \frac{1}{1 + \beta}$, it is straightforward that $f$ is a power function, i.e. there is $\lambda > 0$ such that for any $x \geq 0$, $f(x) = \lambda x^{\beta}$.

> **My question is:**
>
> Does $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow +\infty}{\displaystyle\frac{\int_{0}^{x}{f(t)\mathrm{d}t}}{x f(x)}} = \displaystyle\frac{1}{1 + \beta}$ imply that there is some $\lambda \geq 0$ such that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow +\infty}{\displaystyle\frac{f(x)}{x^{\beta}}} = \lambda$ ?

Comment: I guess in general you want to assume $f$ is Riemann improperly integrable as well in the first assumptions. By the way, you are assuming the limit condition without the pointwise condition for every $x$ and want to check if this implies the conclusion? Am I reading it correctly?

Comment: Shouldn't the limit be $1/(1+\beta)$?

Comment: Of course, let me correct this.

Comment: Hi Son Gohan, let us assume that $f$ is increasing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, $f$ will be “almost” a power function. More precisely, it will be regularly varying with index $\beta$, i.e., of the form $f(x)=x^\beta\cdot\ell(x)$ where $\ell$ is a [slowly varying function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_varying_function), such as $\ell(x):=\log(1+x)$. This is in essence the content of Karamata's theorem (see Theorems 1.5.11 and 1.6.1 of Bingham, Goldie, and Teugel's book “Regular variation”): Karamata's theorem states that a positive, locally bounded function $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$  is a regularly varying function with index $\beta\ge0$ if and only if
$$\frac{x^{\sigma+1}f(x)}{\int_0^xt^\sigma\,f(t)\,\mathrm dt}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\sigma+\beta+1\tag{$C_\sigma$}$$
holds for some $\sigma>-(\beta+1)$. In this case, $(C_\sigma)$ holds for all $\sigma\ge-(\beta+1)$.

The representation theorem (Theorem 1.3.1 in the book) says that we can write any slowly varying function $\ell$ in the form $$\ell(x)=c(x)\exp\left(\int_0^x\varepsilon(u)\frac{\mathrm du}u\right)$$
for some $c$ measurable with $c(x)\to c\in(0,\infty)$ and $\varepsilon(x)\to0$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Do we have results about how the value of $\sigma$ affects the form of the function $f$?

Comment: @Booster I don't think $\sigma$ has a relevant meaning regarding $f$. In fact (as said in the book), if $f$ is $\beta$-regularly-varying then the limit condition holds for all $\sigma\ge-(\beta+1)$. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for this precision. Also, does adding the hypothesis that $f$ is concave imply a more precise result over the representation of the function? I mean in that case we have also for every $a > 0$, $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow +\infty}{ \frac{f(x+a)}{f(x)}} = 1$ and as $C_0$ holds, this implies in the representation form of $f(x) = x^{\beta} \dot l(x)$, that $l$ satisfies for every $a > 0$, $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow}{\frac{l(x+a)}{l(x)}} = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow}{\frac{l(ax)}{l(x)}} = 1$. Do you have any idea how this can shape the expression of $l$?

Comment: @Booster I think $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ell(x+a)}{\ell(x)}=1$ holds for *any* slowly varying function. I’d say the concavity assumption on $f$ more or less amounts to assuming $\beta\in(0,1)$, so doesn’t bring much. And we can find a $\mathcal C^\infty$ function $g$ that is also $\beta$-regularly varying such that $f\sim g$…

Comment: Do you have a proof of the fact that for any slowly varying function $l$, $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow +\infty}{\frac{l(x+a)}{l(x)}} = 1$?

Comment: @Booster Roughly: $$\frac{\ell(x+a)}{\ell(x)}=\frac{c(x+a)}{c(x)}\,\exp\left(\int_x^{x+a}\frac{\varepsilon(u)}u\,\mathrm du\right)=(1+o(1))\exp\!\left(o\!\left(\int_x^{x+a}\frac{\mathrm du}u\right)\right)=(1+o(1))\,\mathrm e^{o(\frac1x)}.$$

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question if you don't mind.  Let $g(x) := \frac{\int_{0}^{x}{f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t}}{xf(x)}$ for every $x > 0$ and $Q_1, \dots, Q_n$ a sequence of random variables in $[a,b]$, $0 < a < b < +\infty$. If almost surely $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty}{g(Q_1 + \dots + Q_n)} = \frac{1}{1 + \beta}$, do we have necessarily that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow +\infty}{g(x)} = \frac{1}{1 + \beta}$? If I have to guess I will say yes, but I am not sure

Comment: @Booster, yes, because $Q_1+\cdots+Q_n\ge na$ almost surely, and $na\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Can you provide a proof of this statement? If for every sequence $(x_n)$ such that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty}{x_n} = +\infty$, $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty}{g(x_n)} = \frac{1}{1 + \beta}$, then $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty}{g(x)} = \frac{1}{1 + \beta}$, but here as you said $Q_1 + \dots + Q_n$ is in $[na, nb]$ and thus goes to infinity linearly, it does not seem obvious that this will imply that $g(x)$ goes to $\frac{1}{1 + \beta}$ as $x \rightarrow +\infty$ unless there is something I am missing

Comment: @Booster: Sorry, I was assuming that $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)$ exists. Obviously if $Q_1,\ldots,Q_n$ are deterministic your premise won't be enough… But for instance if $g$ is continuous and you can show that the sequence $(g(nx))_{n\ge1}$ has limit $\frac1{1+\beta}$ for any $x\in[a,b]$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)$ exists and also equals $\frac1{1+\beta}$.

Comment: Do you have a proof or a reference of this proposition: if $g$ is continuous and for any $x \in [a,b]$, $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow}{g(nx) = \frac{1}{1 + \beta}}$, then $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow +\infty}{g(x)} = \frac{1}{1 + \beta}$?

Comment: @Booster: This is Croft-Kingman lemma, there is a proof in the paper [Ergodic Properties of Continuous-Time Markov Processes and Their Discrete Skeletons](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/plms/s3-13.1.593) by Kingman.

Comment: Many thanks. Do you know if there are some results about the Karamata's theorem when $\beta = +\infty$? Can we provide any representation form of the functions in that case?

Comment: @Booster I do not know. I imagine in this case that the function will increase faster than any polynomial.